# Probability of exactly 1 KQJ before the first ace drawing from a deck of cards.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

A deck of cards is well shuffled. The cards are dealt one by one, until the first time an ace appears.

2. Find the probability that exactly one king, exactly one queen and exactly one jack appear (in any order) before the ace first.

This question was previously asked [1] and my question is an extension of this. My approach was to take the first 4 cards and count the probability these will fall into favourable / all other arangements.

With 12 options for the first card (i.e. KQ or J), 8 options for the second (remaining two), 4 options for the third (final KQJ card) and 4 options for the last card (must be ace), giving

$ \frac{12}{16}.\frac{8}{15}.\frac{4}{14}.\frac{4}{13} = 0.035$

This was the correct answer according to [1].

However, I tried an alternative way to check. Taking every possible arrangement of the first 4 cards, we have 3! options for the order of the KQJ and 1 option for the Ace. For the demoniator we have 4 options for the first card, 4 options for the second ... 4^4. However

$\frac{3!}{4^4} = 0.0234$

I have some feeling that I am overcounting in the demoninator, but am stuck with it. It would be great if the answer could contain the exact logical steps taken to get to why this answer is wrong.

[1]. [A deck of cards is well shuffled. The cards are dealt one by one, until the first time an ace appears](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2156550/a-deck-of-cards-is-well-shuffled-the-cards-are-dealt-one-by-one-until-the-firs)

Comment: Title says at least $1 KQJ$ but the question suggests exactly $1 KQJ$ before the first ace.

Comment: In any case your alternate approach is not correct. Why would the denominator for the first card be $4$ when there are $16$ cards?

Comment: Apologies fixed the title. For denominator the thinking was that, with the focus on the first 4 cards, we are essentially sampling with replacement from the 16 cards. This then gives the total number of 4-card combinations (e.g. AAAA, AAAK ...). This is in contrast to the numerator where the favourable combinations are only (KQJA, KJQA ...)

Comment: But there are $4$ different cards of each rank. So how can the denominator be $4^4$? $AA \color {red} {A}K$ and $ \color {red} {AA}AK$ are different.

Comment: "*...essentially sampling with replacement...*"  No.  No.  Absolutely not.  While yes, one *could* look at the sample space where we ignore the suits of the cards and we organize all `AAAK` results together as one outcome the probability of this occurring is far less common than a result of `AKQJ`, the former compared to the latter occurring at a ratio of $6$ to $16$.  The outcomes counted by stars-and-bars are in almost every problem *not* equally likely to occur.

Comment: The first approach in your question body was the correct one.  The second approach is incorrect and unsalvageable.  Recall... $\Pr(A)=\dfrac{|A|}{|S|}$ with $A$ an event and $S$ the sample space is only ever guaranteed to be true when the outcomes in $S$ are equally likely to occur.  There are two outcomes to the lottery, you win or you lose... but you don't win with probability $\frac{1}{2}$ do you?

Comment: Thanks both for comments that was very useful. Thanks also JMoravitz for the stars-and-bars connection, I see now I was sampling with replacement while not accounting for the order. I will introduce a sanity check to ensure each outcome in the sample space used as demoninator is equally likely. Cheers!